# Firestore rule that matches to part of string

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I created the chat room in firestore's collection. To get the room from the collection by all the users, I added roomId in the document. roomId is generated as follow:

```
const roomId = [uid of userA, uid of userB].sort().join('')  //I3Br2cx7PWavDPlXiQ0TxtYLHpU2dnvzC1hTKbcmRm9NRZyPDL4j9gi2
```

And I'm querying the document as follows:

```
roomsCollection.where("roomId", "==", roomId)
```

It is working nice. Now I want to add the firestore security rule for roomId. So I added the rule as follow but it does not work

```
allow read, update: if resource.data.roomId.matches('.*${request.auth.uid}*') == true
```